# Pickle file tries to load module where stored class instance is defined?

Tags: python, class, pickle

I have a project where my setup involves 4 scripts. I will try to explain my problem via a simplified example. In `script0.py` I define my class:

```
class myClass
  def __init__(self):
      pass #do stuff
```

Then in `script1.py` I define instances of the class:

```
myobj = myClass()
```

Then I import `script1.py` in `script2.py`, and dump the instance to a pickle file:

```
f = open("outfile", wb)
pickle.dump(myobj, f)
```

and finally in `script3.py` where I don't import any other scripts, I load the pickle file

```
f=open("outfile", rb)
pickle.load(f)
```

once I do this, I get an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script1'
```

I am confused as to why `pickle` needs to import `script1.py` in order to load the object again -- if anything, I would have thought that if `pickle` is trying to unpack the object it would be looking for `script0.py` to understand the different elements of the class.

Would you be able to point me to the misconception in my reasoning?

Comment: `pickle` does not store the class of an object when it's dumped, only the class name and what module is it define in — so the latter must be imported to load the class later.

Comment: I see. But then if I dump an attribute of the object such as `myobj.x` (in `script2.py`) instead of the entire object, pickle does not complain anymore when I load the file in another script. Why is that?

Comment: It depends on the type of the attribute. If it's something built-in like an `int` or `str`, as well as many other built-in types like `datetime`, there won't be a problem. The issue is with non-built-in types like instance of a user-defined class.

Comment: It seems like as long as the class is defined in a place that python knows about (such as in packages installed by `pip`), pickle doesn't have a problem loading it. I wonder then if there is a way to get around the issue? Is there somehow a way to also dump the module where the instance is defined so that pickle knows about it during `load`?

Comment: The class definition doesn't have to be "installed", just in a module that can be imported when the class instance is loaded. You can dump the source code for the module defining the class. You will need to load it and recreate the module before loading instance of the class. From what I understand the third-party [`dill` module](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) provides ways to save and extract the source code of functions and classes.